# How can I find a path between two abstract nodes

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, path-finding, scientific-computing

I wish to test the "small world" or "Six degrees of separation" hypothesis, the theory that any human can reach another through just 6 mutual friends. (i.e. a friend of a friend of a friend of a friend of a friend of a friend)

Example node data (JSON):

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "friends": [
        "Foo Bar",
        "John Doe"
    ]
}
```

There would be hundreds of objects just like these, each linking to one another. I want to find the shortest path between them. Would a pathfinding algorithm such as those found in games be suitable for abstract concepts like this (I.e.: concepts that are not representable in a 2D or 3D world) or is there a more elegant solution?

I know that I could just loop through the friends list multiple times with increasing depths of search, but this would be an inelegant solution, taking a very long time with large amounts of data.

I am already well aware of pathfinding algorithms such as A*, but I was simply unsure whether this is an appropriate use for them

At the very least the program should output a string such as "It takes x steps to get from person1 to person2" It would be nice to know the intermediary people and possibly even obtain a nice web/graph from it, too.

Comment: Would be nice to know the output you expect to create from it

Answer (score 1):

This link [Finding Paths in Graphs](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/PathsInGraphs07.pdf) (page 33,34) gives you a powerful algorithm for graphs, where you assume, that these are small-world graphs!

Before implementing the algorithm, you should transform your json-data to a graph with a reasonable fast data-structure (dense vs. sparse graph-representation).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Floyd Warshall for all nodes shortest paths.Complexity is O(N^3)

Or you could run a djikstra from each node and compute it in O(ElogV * N) time

Here's a good implementation http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-16-floyd-warshall-algorithm/